# How to leave connection to SFTP open, while other bash commands run

Tags: bash, sftp, scp

**Problem**

I am using sshpass & scp to download files from a SFTP server, but the files I download are small and I end up making so many requests in a short period of time, that my server gets slowed because it looks suspicious.

Is it possible to leave the ssh connection open, while the bash script downloads the initial file, processes the file and then moves onto the next file in a loop?

Is there a better way to tackle this problem, bearing in mind that I'm stuck with the bad SFTP they have?

**Example Code**

```
 while read i; do
        # i in this case, is the entire file path
        # so we can select the last part 
        just_filepath=$(echo $i  | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}')

        if sshpass -f ftp_pass.txt scp -r $ftp_user_address:$i "clients/$bq_dataset/"$just_filepath >> "debug/upload_dl_debug.log" 2>&1; then
            bash_log "successfully downloaded $just_filepath from FTP"
        else
            bash_log "failed to download $just_filepath from FTP"
        fi

        ...
        processExternalLogs $just_filepath
        ((x++))
done <ftp_file_list.txt
```

**Background**

I have a small Digital Ocean server, which is being used to process logs before feeding them to a BigQuery to be analysed.

Because the server doesn't have much space, the bash script which does all the processing downloads each file one by one, processes it, then uploads it into BigQuery before deleting the file to free up space for future ones.

The client's SFTP I'm having to work with at the moment is a cheap one on public hosting that they have no control over.

Because the files I'm downloading are so small and processing is so quick, multiple attempts to connect with the SFTP end up looking suspicious (I presume) and I end up getting rate limited. The script still works, it's just super slow.

There are too many files to download them all at once to my DO box and so I'm wondering if there is a clever way where I can just leave the SFTP connection open, while the processing of the logs runs.

Comment: Do you want a shell solution or something like python could be used?

Comment: Don’t copy the files from your script and use [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs)